# Explicitly assigning port number to client in SocketIO.Client() module in python

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, fastapi, flask-socketio

I am trying to specify host and port number for socketio.Client() in python and then want to connect to a server. But unfortunately I couldn't find any bind functions for the "socketio" package in python.

Also I have seen a package called "socket" in python which provides the bind() method . But unfortunately it doesn't provide any decorators like on, emit ,events .So I am willing to use any modern python socket packages which allow me to specify client host and port in sockets.

Any help on this is appreciated..

Comment: _`http_session` – an initialized requests.Session object to be used when sending requests to the server. Use it if you need to add special client options such as proxy servers, SSL certificates, etc._ - So you probably have to go through the `requests` library to do a bind, but I'm not sure what the actual use case is for specifying a specific client port or ip.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

The host and port number of the server are specified in the `connect()`. Are you reading the [documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#connecting-to-a-server)? Everything is explained right there.

```py
sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
```

Comment: No. My question was not about connecting to server. That is briefly documented. My apologize if the question was not clear. Let me say with an example. Suppose if am connecting to a server using sio.connect() ..connection gets established successfully. But the allocated client port is random say 127.0.0.1:12345 . So I just wanted to set the client port manually say 127.0.0.1:8000. I saw some function like "bind" in socket module. But I need to do same thing by setting the client port manually in socket.io package or any other package other than "socket".

Comment: The Socket.IO client does not work at a low level, it relies on dependencies for actual network connections. So you will need to see if the HTTP and WebSocket clients that you are using provide this option. You can pass an initialized HTTP/WS client session for the Socket.IO client to use.